# Is it possible to assign IP both to an Interface and Bridge?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

Is it possible to assign an interface to a bridge and give different addresses to both?

In my case public IP of bridge is working but LAN address on interface is not working.

Something like:

```
iface eno1 inet static
address 10.10.10.11
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface vmbr0 inet static
address [public IP]
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway [GW IP]
bridge_ports eno1
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign multiple IPs to the same machine on the same network. You can assign multiple IPs to the same interface as well. Reasons for doing this vary. You might do this if there was more than one LAN on the same data-link layer network, which is unusual to begin with.

Is there a particular reasons you want to assign multiple IPs to the same machine on the same network?